# How to use htaccess to redirect only certain URL's to a different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two ecommerce websites abc.com and pqr.com .In a couple of months time I plan to close down abc.com and have started listing all products on pqr.com . How can I redirect only a certain urls on the old website to the new one keeping other URL's as is.

e.g. abc.com/example-product should redirect to pqr.com/example-product 
abc.com/example-product-2 should not redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^example-product/?$ http://pqr.com/$0 [L,NC,R=301]
```